# how to get list of files matching a pattern

Tags: java, regex, eclipse-plugin

From my eclipse plugin i open a dialog that has two fields. 1 for folder selection and 2nd for pattern, where user can select a folder and enter a pattern.
I need to list out all the files from that folder that match the pattern. For

ex: if user wants the list of files whose name ends with DAO, they will give *DAO in the pattern text box. or

if they want all file starting with My they will give My* in the pattern.

I get the list of IResource objects from the Ifolder that is selected. I loop through the list and match the file name and pattern with the below code.

pattern -- holds the value user enters in the dialog box.
fileName -- file name  -- IResource.getName().

```
final Pattern pattrn = Pattern.compile(pattern);
final Matcher matcher = pattrn.matcher(fileName);
return matcher.matches();
```

This code gives error 
for ex 1:
Dangling meta character '*' near index 0
*DAO

for ex 2: returns true for any file name

How should i match the pattern and with the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya, `Pattern.compile` method would take  regex as parameter not glob. You need to add `.` before the `*` symbol.

To match all the file names endswith `DAO`

```
final Pattern pattrn = Pattern.compile(".*DAO$");
```

If you want the files starting with `M` and ends with `DAO`, then you may try this,

```
final Pattern pattrn = Pattern.compile("^M.*DAO$");
```

Anchors won't be needed if you pass the above regex in `matches` method.

```
filename.matches(".*DAO");
filename.matches("M.*DAO");
```